# Is this grammatically incorrect to say "honestly, I feel like a child myself sometimes"?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

Is it grammatically incorrect to say:

> honestly, I feel like a child myself sometimes

Is the rule "never use myself with feel" relevant here?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I hope you like the place and decide to visit often. You might want to [take the tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) or to read the [Contributor's guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/91457). The guide has a lot of helpful information on how best to ask, and answer, questions here on ELL.

Comment: Please identify the actual rule (i.e., cite where it comes from). Otherwise I think that it may be hard to address your last question.

Answer (score 3):

This is grammatically correct. "Myself" is being used as an intensive pronoun, not as a reflexive pronoun, so the "never use feel with myself" rule does not apply.

Comment: (Incidentally, I'm not sure if you can *never* use "I feel myself" with "myself" as a reflexive pronoun. "I felt myself getting angry" sounds valid to me.)